# NodeJS deletes one folder but fails on another identical one (EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir)

Tags: node.js, windows

I have a timelapse program that I wrote myself, using NodeJS. It takes a screenshot once per second while ever the computer is unlocked, and for each day it creates a new subdirectory named the current date. Thus I have a heap of directories like this:

[image]

The screenshot program runs at logon as the main user of the computer (using Task Scheduler).

I also have another NodeJS program that compiles the screenshot images into videos (using ffmpeg), and after the video is created it removes all files from within the directory and then removes the directory.

My problem is that for some reason while the compiling Node script successfully deletes the images inside each date-named folder, it's unable to delete the empty directories, failing with:

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'E:\timelapses\daily\2020-04-10\'`

Initially I thought it was a permissions issue, so I ran the video-compiler as administrator. No change, it still failed trying to delete the empty directory. Then I tried ensuring every date-named folder and the parent directory had `Full control`:

[image]

Still fails to delete! Getting frustrated, I created a simplified test script, literally just:

```
let fs = require('fs');

fs.rmdirSync('test');
fs.rmdirSync('test2');
```

The `test` folder is one I created myself (right-click > New > Folder), and the `test2` folder is a copy (right-click > Copy > Paste) of one of the empty folders that NodeJS can't delete. Upon running that script the `test` folder instantly disappears but the `test2` folder remains, and the script errors.

I'm so confused! Both folders look 100% identical in Properties, both are owned by me (the local user), both are Read Only.

What could be different? One folder was created by a regular Explorer window, the other by a NodeJS program. They're both appear identical as far as I can see. Both are totally empty as far as I can see (hidden and system files visible in Explorer, I see no files). The one that won't delete was a copy-paste, so it can't be held open by some program (and LockHunter shows no results). Are there some special, hidden attributes that I can't see?

In case it wasn't obvious, I'm on Windows 10. Node is `v10.15.3` but the folder that refuses to delete was created with `v8.16.1` (due to module incompatibilities).

Help!

Comment: I'd guess that windows has one of the directories open still from a previous operation. Can you post the overall file operations from your encode/delete process.

Comment: @Matt Yes but I copy-pasted one of the directories that won't delete and used that in the test, so it shouldn't be possible for it to still be open. The delete process can be considered to be the test script above (since that replicates the issue), and the folders are created with `fs.mkdirSync(directory);`. Hmm actually, that gives me an idea. I'll create another test script to see if simply creating a directory results in one that can't be deleted with Node.

Comment: windows explorer can hold the dir lock as well

Comment: @Matt Well sure but lockhunter doesn't find anything, and I've never had explorer hold a lock like that unless there's a reason (e.g. generating thumbnails). But I'm attempting to create a simplified replication test.

Comment: hmm.. maybe that's just a command prompt that holds it then

Comment: @Matt But again, lockhunter shows nothing (not that it's 100% reliable) and I copy-pasted the folder, which makes me _really_ think it's not an open handle. On the other hand I have absolutely no idea what it could be instead so who am I to suggest otherwise....

Comment: yeah, no idea what else it could be.

Comment: @Matt Aha, it finally occurred to me that Node is just doing `rmdir`, which is a standard Windows command. Doing `rmdir test2` myself I get `Access is denied`, so it's clearly not a Node issue. That gives me something else to Google for at least.

Comment: cool. maybe [accesschk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accesschk) or [accessenum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accessenum) might highlight a difference